# Cannot stop an executing Cypher query in Galaxybase

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, opencypher

In the Galaxybase cluster management platform (51314 interface)-Services-Cypher execution list, the Cypher statement being executed does not take effect immediately after clicking Stop. What should I do to stop a cypher query execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query task cannot be stopped immediately at some stages of execution. For example, the task cannot be stopped immediately during the sorting process, but the task will be marked with a stop status, and then the task will be stopped as soon as it enters the status verification phase.